# Vue typescript ref: Cannot create property 'value' on boolean 'false'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I'm using vue with typescript and headless ui. When I try to show a dialog following this example: https://headlessui.dev/vue/dialog, I get the error: Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'Ref'

I declare the isOpen variable in my component class:

```
private readonly isOpen = ref<boolean>(false);
```

The html for the button that is opening the dialog is:

```
<button class="btn" @click="toggleGuestList(true)">View list</button>
```

The method for toggling the dialog is:

```
public toggleGuestList(toggle:boolean) {
   this.isOpen.value =  toggle;
}
```

It is when this method is activated I get the error:

> Cannot create property 'value' on boolean 'false'

It seems isOpen is resolved as a plain boolean. How can I force it to see it as a ref? I tried (this.isOpen as Ref< boolean >).value = true, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, did you find any solution to this? casting to Ref<boolean> shouldn't make any difference given that it would just cast the type but not the data. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I gave up and decided to abandon vue-typescript. Now I've reconfigured my project to use regular java script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's an old one, but i get the similar issue, because don't read doc carefully .

Maybe someone will find it useful, so i left answer here.

**ANSWER** [FROM DOC]:

> Note that refs returned from setup are automatically shallow unwrapped
> when accessed in the template so you do not need to use .value when
> accessing them. They are also unwrapped in the same way when accessed
> on this.

```
setup() {
    const isOpen = ref<boolean>(false);
},
methods: {
    public toggleGuestList(toggle:boolean) {
        this.isOpen.value = toggle; // will not work (as isOpen already unwrapped)
        this.isOpen = toggle;  // will work
    }
}
```

If you use method inside `setup` then:

```
setup() {
    const isOpen = ref<boolean>(false);

    function toggleGuestList(toggle:boolean) {
        this.isOpen.value = toggle; // will not work as we should access to isOpen without this inside setup
        isOpen.value = toggle; // will work
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to bind to component, use `isOpen.value` not `isOpen`.